# CSV Parsing - Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I am trying to parse a CSV but i am getting some issues. Below is the code i used for parsing CSV:

```
let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "test_application_data - Sheet 1", withExtension: "csv")
let content = try String(contentsOf: fileURL!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
let parsedCSV: [[String]] = content.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",")}
```

And this is the data in the CSV i am parsing :

```
Item 9,Description 9,image url 
"Item 10 Extra line 1 Extra line 2 Extra line 3",Description 10,image url
```

So by using above code i get correct response for first row i.e `Item 9` but i am getting malformed response for `Item 10`

How can i correctly parse both rows?

[image]

Comment: Use a custom newline character or implement some logic that can handle multiline columns in your csv.

Comment: @AamirR check my screenshot, the column has multiple rows, and when i parse i get item 10 only from that column? But i need the full column from item 10 to Extra line 3.

Comment: @FruitAddict any pointers?

Comment: Since the file is located in your bundle you are encouraged to use a more reasonable (and reliable) text format like JSON or Property List.

Comment: @vadian this is just a test, i ll be fetching CSV information from endpoint, so as i said i cant control structure of the CSV file.

Comment: lol who downvoted this question :) how can be this downvoted man

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The RFC for CSV: [Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files(RFC-4180)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)

Not all CSV data or CSV processors conform to all descriptions of this RFC, but generally, fields enclosed within double-quotes can contain:

- newlines
- commas
- escaped double-quotes (`""` represents a single double-quote)

This code is a little bit simplified than RFC-4180, but handles all three cases above:

**UPDATE** This old code does not handle CRLF well. (Which is a valid newline in RFC-4180.) I added a new code at the bottom, please check it.
Thanks to Jay.

```
import Foundation

let csvText = """
Item 9,Description 9,image url
"Item 10
Extra line 1
Extra line 2
Extra line 3",Description 10,image url
"Item 11
Csv item can contain ""double quote"" and comma(,)", Description 11 ,image url
"""

let pattern = "[ \r\t]*(?:\"((?:[^\"]|\"\")*)\"|([^,\"\\n]*))[ \t]*([,\\n]|$)"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)

var result: [[String]] = []
var record: [String] = []
let offset: Int = 0
regex.enumerateMatches(in: csvText, options: .anchored, range: NSRange(0..<csvText.utf16.count)) {match, flags, stop in
    guard let match = match else {fatalError()}
    if match.range(at: 1).location != NSNotFound {
        let field = csvText[Range(match.range(at: 1), in: csvText)!].replacingOccurrences(of: "\"\"", with: "\"")
        record.append(field)
    } else if match.range(at: 2).location != NSNotFound {
        let field = csvText[Range(match.range(at: 2), in: csvText)!].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        record.append(field)
    }
    let separator = csvText[Range(match.range(at: 3), in: csvText)!]
    switch separator {
    case "\n": //newline
        result.append(record)
        record = []
    case "": //end of text
        //Ignoring empty last line...
        if record.count > 1 || (record.count == 1 && !record[0].isEmpty) {
            result.append(record)
        }
        stop.pointee = true
    default: //comma
        break
    }
}
print(result)
```

(Intended to test in a Playground.)

---

**New code**, CRLF ready.

```
import Foundation

let csvText =  "Field0,Field1\r\n"

let pattern = "[ \t]*(?:\"((?:[^\"]|\"\")*)\"|([^,\"\r\\n]*))[ \t]*(,|\r\\n?|\\n|$)"
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern)

var result: [[String]] = []
var record: [String] = []
let offset: Int = 0
regex.enumerateMatches(in: csvText, options: .anchored, range: NSRange(0..<csvText.utf16.count)) {match, flags, stop in
    guard let match = match else {fatalError()}
    if let quotedRange = Range(match.range(at: 1), in: csvText) {
        let field = csvText[quotedRange].replacingOccurrences(of: "\"\"", with: "\"")
        record.append(field)
    } else if let range = Range(match.range(at: 2), in: csvText) {
        let field = csvText[range].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        record.append(field)
    }
    let separator = csvText[Range(match.range(at: 3), in: csvText)!]
    switch separator {
    case "": //end of text
        //Ignoring empty last line...
        if record.count > 1 || (record.count == 1 && !record[0].isEmpty) {
            result.append(record)
        }
        stop.pointee = true
    case ",": //comma
        break
    default: //newline
        result.append(record)
        record = []
    }
}
print(result) //->[["Field0", "Field1"]]
```

Comment: This is great code but seems to crash on line delimiters with /r/n eg CRLF. For example a string like this "Field0,Field1\r\n" crashes whereas a string like this "Field0,Field1\r" or this "Field0,Field1\n" work correctly. Possible solution is to strip the CR (\r) from the line before parsing it.

Comment: @Jay, thanks so much. Seems `Range.init(_:in:)` returns nil when an `NSRange` pointing between CR & LF, that's reasonable as CRLF is a single Character in Swift. I had ignored many possible result when there are any CRLFs. I add an updated code, please try.

Comment: Brilliant, and a very good explanation. Looks like that corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line of code:

```
content.components(separatedBy: "\n")
```

It separates your csv file into rows based on the newline character. There are newline characters in your `"Item 10 Extra line 1 Extra line 2 Extra line 3"` String so each extra line is getting treated as a different row, so in the end you get the wrong result.

I'd suggest escaping the newline characters in your multiline text column or getting rid of them altogether. You can also modyfy the input file so the newline delimeter isn't `\n` at the end of each row but something custom (a string that won't appear elsewhere in the csv file).

Comment: I have no control on input file, so i cant change this. if you have anything specific in your mind , do share :)

Comment: You could base your row building on number of columns instead of delimeters, you know there are always 3 columns separated by ','. Treat the text as a long string that you separate by ',' ignoring the newline characters

Comment: @Shabirjan This is beyond the abilities of `.components(...` - check out `NSRegularExpression`...

Comment: @Grimxn how can i use `NSRegularExpression` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think best option to use TabularData https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tabulardata

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Table", withExtension: "csv"),
   let data = try? DataFrame.init(contentsOfCSVFile: url) {
    print(data.rows)
    
    let array: [Model] = data.rows.map { row in
        let value1 = row["ColumnKey1", String.self]
        let value2 = row["ColumnKey2", String.self]
        return Model(value1: value1, value2: value2)
    }
    print(array)
} else {
    print("Error")
}
```

Comment: You should mention that this is available as of iOS 15.0/macOS 12.0. And what is `Model`? That's not part of the TabularData framework.